# HttpURlConnection not connecting

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am making a HttpUrlConnection with an Usgs API. This is my Url:

"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/queryformat=geojson&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=6&limit=10"

After thoroughly debugging, it seems that after connection.connect connection fails and jsonResponse is empty.

```
 public static String makeHttprequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(1000000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(1500000);

            connection.connect();

            stream = connection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readfromstream(stream);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", "Error while making request");
        }

        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

[This is Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0qfH.png)

Comment: Use Retrofit for networking. Don't use HttpURLConnection since you're more likely to make mistakes

Comment: The error says you have a problem parsing the JSON. Perhaps the JSON is not in the correct format.

Comment: Can you post more relevant code from Earthquake_loader? Also the url should be [this](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=6&limit=10)

Comment: it was giving error about jason parsing because  HttpUrlConnection was giving null output.

Comment: Anyways there was not problem with code but emulator was not picking up the internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good. It seems to me that you have no internet connection in your running devices. Probably you are using emulator in your computer which is not connected to internet.

Please try to run in real device. It is working perfect for me.

A bit advice, please try to use libraries such as Retrofit or OkHttp. They are very much easier and handier than these old ways.

If you insist using HttpURLConnection, try the following

```
URL url = new URL(yourUrlString);
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
   } finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

Or for more formal use of HttpURLConnection, visit here. It shows several proper use of HttpURLConnection APIs.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 0):

just tried my app on real device everything is working as expected there might be problem with emulator.